# Is YDL.net's Eclipse CUDA plugin ready for CUDA 4.0

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cuda

I've just installed the CUDA 4.0 Toolkit, and also the [CUDA plugin](http://ydl.net/eclipse_cuda_plugin/userdoc.shtml) for Eclipse Helios on top of an AMD64 Ubuntu 10.10 machine. I have been able to compile successfully all of the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK examples, so my build system looks fine. But I cannot make the Hello World CUDA template of the plugin to compile on Eclipse, it doesn't seem to find the runtime libraries, as shown below:

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project holamundo ****

make all 
cc   holamundo.o   -o holamundo
holamundo.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_44_tmpxft_000022c4_00000000_4_holamundo_cpp1_ii_main()':
tmpxft_000022c4_00000000-1_holamundo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
holamundo.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_000022c4_00000000-1_holamundo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `cudaMalloc'
tmpxft_000022c4_00000000-1_holamundo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `cudaConfigureCall'
tmpxft_000022c4_00000000-1_holamundo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
tmpxft_000022c4_00000000-1_holamundo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to `cudaFree'
tmpxft_000022c4_00000000-1_holamundo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `HelloWorld_kernel(int, char*)'
holamundo.o: In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_000022c4_00000000-1_holamundo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
holamundo.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [holamundo] Error 1
```

Has anyone already tried to use the plugin with version 4.0 of the CUDA toolkit? It looks as if it was designed only for versions 3.x compatibility, although I have not tested this.

Comment: It looks like your project isn't linking the CUDA runtime library. That isn't particular to CUDA 4.0, I would have thought.

Comment: But I have corectly set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by means of ldconfig. I just don't know, does Eclipse know about this environment variable?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effect on compilation, it controls how shared libraries are found at run time....

Comment: Thanks @talonmies for the enlightenment! The next step on this road is letting Eclipse/the plugin know where the libraries are. But there is no C/C++ Build\Settings\Libraries list under either NVIDA CUDA compiler or GCC compiler, and neither does adding "-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart" to the miscellaneous entry of NVIDIA CUDA compiler work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that there is now Nsight Eclipse Edition that is a part of CUDA Toolkit. It supports all new CUDA Toolkit 5.0 features.